# Codeigniter: DB Cache check if record loaded from Database OR from Cache

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, caching

I'm implementing a DB cache in Codeigniter and want to check if the record or the cache file EXISTS against the query.

As far as I read the Codeigniter [Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/caching.html) probably, there is no way to check it. So, can anyone give me a hint if its possible?

Here is the flowchart that I would like to achieve

```
if (!$this->db->query_exists("QUERY HERE"))
    // DO SOMETHING. Query Doesn't exists in CACHE

// Run the query in any case
$this->db->query("QUERY HERE");
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have to check if cache file exists. Check naming of those files. It is named by URI segments. Test few queries and your will conclude naming convention for those files.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you need/want to do this. Assuming query caching is enabled, the Codeigniter DB driver already does this checking and will use a cached query if it exists or will perform the query and cache it if not. The main thing you have to implement is clearing the appropriate cache when you perform record inserts, updates, or deletions that invalidate the cached results.

That said, the easiest way to determine if a cache exists is the `CI_DB_Cache::read($sql)` method. That method returns FALSE if a matching cache file is not found.

The DB driver has a public property - $CACHE. (Yes, it's an all uppercase variable name.) $CACHE is an instance of the `CI_DB_Cache` class.

This property will only be defined after a read type query has been performed. That could be a "catch 22" - you can't check for a cache file until a read query is performed, but you want to check before performing one.

Take a look at `protected function _cache_init()` in `/system/database/DB_driver.php` to see how the `CI_DB_Cache` class is instantiated. You might need to implement the same sort of thing in your code.

You might also find it useful to see how `$this->CACHE` is used in `public function query($sql, $binds = FALSE, $return_object = NULL)` in `/system/database/DB_driver.php`.

You **might** be able to determine if the query in question exists by using the approach that follows. I say **might** because I have not tested this.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from some_table";
//check that CACHE is defined
if(isset($this->db->CACHE))
{
    $query = $this->db->CACHE->read($sql);

    if($query === FALSE)
    {
         // DO SOMETHING. Query Doesn't exists in CACHE
    }
}
```

`$query` will be a query result object if the cache is found.

However, you **have to delete the cache** before you can accomplish

```
// Run the query in any case
$this->db->query("QUERY HERE");
```

Without the delete you're going to end up with the same query result object you have already retrieved.

Keep in mind that the Caching class is completely dependent on the URI being requested by the browser. Caching uses the first two URI segments (controller class name and function name) to determine the folder that holds the cache file.